# Custom grid displays an empty string

Tags: adminhtml, magento-1.8, grid

## Synopsis

I have a custom module which is designed to allow attachments to be uploaded for a specific product.  I have done some research and lot's of trial and error, but I think my lack of understanding is partly the reason why it isn't working.

Along with my research i've followed several tutorials, and only one of them used their own custom table except it was still based on an existing table.

## My goal

I am attempting to accomplish - A `grid` that will display data from a custom table in the database.

---

**./controllers/Adminhtml/Product/Uploader/AttachmentController.php**

```
class Vendor_ProductUploader_Adminhtml_Product_Uploader_AttachmentController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
    /**
     * Array of actions that can be processed without a secret key validation.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_publicActions = array();


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor_productuploader/adminhtml_attachment'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

        $response = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('vendor_productuploader/adminhtml_attachment_grid')
            ->toHtml();

        $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
    }
}
```

**./Block/Adminhtml/Attachment.php**

```
class Vendor_ProductUploader_Block_Adminhtml_Attachment
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'productuploader';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_product_uploader';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('vendor_productuploader')->__('Product Attachments');
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('export_button');
    }
}
```

**./Block/Adminhtml/Attachment/Grid.php**

```
class Vendor_ProductUploader_Block_Adminhtml_Attachment_Grid
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultSort('updated_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('vendor_productuploader/attachment')
            ->getCollection();

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('vendor_productuploader')->__('ID'),
            'index'  => 'entity_id',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('label', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('vendor_productuploader')->__('File Name'),
            'index'  => 'label',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('description', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('vendor_productuploader')->__('Description'),
            'index'  => 'description',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('vendor_productuploader')->__('Created At'),
            'type'   => 'date',
            'index'  => 'created_at',
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container::_prepareLayout` you will see that it creates the grid model using:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid'
```

The variables used are in my opinion a little bit misleading. But the outcome is that in your class `Block/Adminhtml/Attachment.php` you would need to use the following in order to generate the correct block instance:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_blockGroup = 'vendor_productuploader';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_attachment';
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Misleading? I agree.  I shall take your advice and let you know how I get on, but also thanks for the initial information.

Comment: Assumably when the convention was originally chosen the names of the block for the grid (and container) mapped to the name of the controller that rendered the grid, hence then naming. But at some point this has deviated.

Answer (score 0):

inside this file /Block/Adminhtml/Attachment.php.

$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_product_uploader'; 
this line should be
$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_attachment';

Try now.